# How do I make my image appear bigger on screens with higher resolutions?

Tags: android, imageview, dpi, android-resolution

On my Android app, I have a screen with an image.

The image is 600px wide. On my Galaxy SIII, this looks how I want it to look. But on phones with double the resolution it looks really small.

With shape objects that I define in `xml`, it's easy to define the width in dp units so it looks consistent on all phones.

But how do I do the same with an image that is physically only a certain amount of pixels?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
and http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: I was going to link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366102/how-to-auto-scale-an-image-for-all-resolutions

Answer (score 0):

Use different different Resolution images for each screen size

Answer (score 0):

You can get the screen resolution and then adjust your image

```
 Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
 Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: How do you adjust the size of the image programatically?

Comment: there are many ways to do that one of the ways is  that your can create a linearlayout in your xml file and assign it an id. Then initialize that layout in your activity and create a new imageview after determining the resolution set the width and height of the image and add it to the layout. Please mark this answer as correct if I helped you thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use different images for different screens See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html or change scaletype on imageview.